# Generic react component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-component

I'm building a form component in react using typescript that takes a 'fieldStructures' and an 'onSubmit' prop.

```
type FieldStructure {
    type: 'text';
    name: string;
    label?: string;
    helpText?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    multiline?: boolean;
} | {
    type: 'date';
    name: string;
    label?: string;
    helpText?: string;
    required?: boolean;
} | {
    type: 'option';
    name: string;
    label?: string;
    helpText?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    options: string[];
    multi?: boolean;
} | {
    type: 'file';
    name: string;
    label?: string;
    helpText?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    fileTypes?: string[];
}

type FieldValue <T extends FieldType = any> =
    T extends 'text' ? string
    : T extends 'date' ? Date | null
    : T extends 'option' ? string | string[] | null
    : T extends 'file' ? string | File | null
    : string | string[] | Date | File | null

interface FormModalProps {
    fieldStructures: FieldStructure[];
    handleSubmit: (values: { [key: string]: FieldValue }) => void | Promise<void>;
}

export const FormModal: React.FC<FormModalProps> = ({
    fieldStructures,
    handleSubmit
}) => { ... }
```

This works great for just making the component but not so much for using it. I want the type of the values parameter to rely on what is passed to the fieldStructures parameter like this...

```
interface FormValues <T extends FieldStructure[]> {
    //keys are the names of each field structure
    //values are FieldValue<field structure type>
}

interface FormModalProps <T extends FieldStructure[]> {
    fieldStructures: T;
    handleSubmit: (values: FormValues<T>) => void | Promise<void>;
}
```

This example feels like an over-simplification, but does anyone know of a way to achieve the same result?

the full code is available on my github at:
https://github.com/baldwin-design-co/bdc-components/blob/master/src/form%20modal/form-modal.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be specifying a type for each structure, that extends a common type with a designated property (in your case, `type`).
Then for each form, you need to receive a config that extends a common config as well. The FormValue than will be a simple `keyof T`.

Check this example below:

```js
// Field types

export interface FieldStructure {
    type: 'text' | 'date';
}

export interface TextField extends FieldStructure {
    type: 'text';
    label: string;
}

export interface DateField extends FieldStructure {
    type: 'date';
    label: string;
}

// Calculate the value based on field type

export type FieldValue<T extends FieldStructure> = 
    T extends TextField ? string
    : T extends DateField ? Date | null
    : string | Date | null ;
    
// Types the form itself

type FormConfig = {[key: string]: FieldStructure}

// Gets the form value based on the type of each field
type FormValue<T extends FormConfig> = {
    [k in keyof T]: FieldValue<T[k]>
}


// Example of usage:

interface MyFormConfig extends FormConfig {
   a: TextField;
   b: DateField
}
```

Comment: So that works great to model the type relationship, but how do I actually implement that into the component I tried `interface FormModalProps <T extends FormConfig> { formConfig: T; handleSubmit: (values: FormValues<T>) => void | Promise<void>; } `but then when I define the component I also have to define the form config `const FormModal: React.FC<FormModalProps> = (props) => { ... }` 'Generic type 'FormModalProps<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).'

Comment: Have you tried to set a default type for T?
Like: `interface FormModalProps<T extends FormConfig = FormConfig>`

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to make the component itself generic and just pass the value of that generic to the props. Thanks so much for your help I've been trying to get this working for weeks.